# Different results for concrete and abstract model

Tags: pyomo

I am new to Pysp and Pyomo. When I was trying to run the concrete model from the farmer example, I run the command suggested in the ReadMe file (except for changing the model from abstract to concrete)  and I got a different result (98000) for the concrete model, from the abstract model (-118600) of the farmer problem.

I could get the same result for the abstract model on my computer as suggested in the ReadMe file. Does anyone have an idea about what has caused this issue? Did I do something wrong? Thank you!
Best,
Yeming

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCgD9.png)

Comment: Is this working when you run the farmer example with the ConcreteModel line?

Comment: Yep, it works but the result does not look correct.

Comment: Sorry for being insistant, in order to find if it is because you didn't convert your problem into a `ConcreteModel` that you do not get something that you think is correct, I need to know if running the example exactly as it is gives you the same result as we can see in the example. That would be a first step. It might just be because you didn't convert your problem into a ConcreteModel. FYI, using a `ConcreteModel` is a very important step. Secondly, what makes you think that it didn't work? And last, what did you try? What line(s) exactly did you omitted? That would help us answer you.